# Retrieving Input Text Value

Tags: javascript, html

For the following HTML

```
<form>
    Enter hash here: <input type="text" name="hash">
       <button type="submit" formaction="/tasks/">Retrieve Url</button>
</form>
```

How can I re-direct the user to `/tasks/A` where `A` = whatever the user typed in the "hash" `<input>` box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value) will help.

It do exactly the same thing you want with example.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to either prevent the submit's default action [(`event.preventDefault();`)](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), or change the button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, then use JavaScript to set the form's action. Here's some jQuery that could do the job for you:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    //set the form action
    $('form').attr('action', '/tasks/'+$('input[type="text"]').val())
    //submit the form
    .submit();
});
```

See a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/BQ8MW/

Answer (score -1):

You could use a temporary post and redirect. For example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hash'])){
header("Location:/tasks/" . $_POST['hash']);
}
?>
```

Or if you want you could use AJAX to collect the value and then redirecting without the refresh.